# VBA to compare multiple column values then replace in multiple worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, replace, excel-2010

I need to compare values in columns E & F of a workbook that has over 400 sheets, if E & F are equal, replace column F with new text.
I am quite new to excel and i have tried many different methods from google.

the below (from google) works ok for 1 sheet, but i need it to do all sheets.

```
Sub findcomparereplace()
Dim wsh As Worksheet, i As Long, lngEndRowInv As Long
Set wsh = ActiveSheet

i = 2
lngEndRowInv = wsh.Range("E" & wsh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
While i <= lngEndRowInv
If Cells(i, "E") Like "*myvalue1*" And Cells(i, "F") Like "*myvalue1*" 
Then
Cells(i, "F").Value = "myvalue2"
End If
i = i + 1
Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate sheets like so:

```
Sub findcomparereplace()
    Dim wsh As Worksheet, i As Long, lngEndRowInv As Long

    For Each wsh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        i = 2
        lngEndRowInv = wsh.Range("E" & wsh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        While i <= lngEndRowInv
            If wsh.Cells(i, "E") Like "*myvalue1*" And wsh.Cells(i, "F") Like "*myvalue1*" Then
                wsh.Cells(i, "F").Value = "myvalue2"
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Wend
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome dude. Please mark as the answer. Also it occured to me you may want to watch it's progress, in which case add a new line `wsh.Activate` after the `For Each...` line

Comment: Thanks rayzinnz. i will try that out later. thanks again for your help. ;-)